# How should I get signal when "mouse is on the button?" (Just on, Not pressed)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to handle the event when the mouse cursor is on the button.
For example, it is the situation like we should brightening the color of buttons
when the mouse cursor is on.

I searched a lot, but there was all the talking about

-->self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.function)

Is there any way to use btn1 connection like,
--> self.btn1.mouse_Crusor_On.connect(self.fuction)   ??

If it is impossible, what I need to know is the way how to use button.clicked
Event as a CONDITION in 'if' syntax.

- There are two groups of "#" below, it is the part with problem.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
import os


LocationX=list(range(50,1500,50))
LocationY=list(range(50,850,50))


class MainPage(QWidget):  

    def __init__(self, title="ATI: "):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('C:\\Users\\IAN\\Desktop\\GUI 연구\\images\\Icon.png')) 
        self.title = title
        self.left = 250
        self.top = 250
        self.width = 1500
        self.height = 850
        self.widget()
        self.setGeometry(30,50,1200,800)

    def widget(self):
        x=0
        y=0
        self.text="x:{0}, y:{1}".format(x,y) 
        self.label_mouseTest = QLabel(self.text, self)
        self.label_mouseTest.setGeometry(0,0,300,40)
        self.label_mouseTest.move(10,0)



        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.resize(self.width, self.height) # self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.move(self.left, self.top)

        x1=LocationX[2] 
        y1=LocationY[5]



        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self, text="임의폴더")
        self.btn1.setToolTip("/Main/임의폴더")
        self.btn1.move(x1-20,y1+30) 
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.open_folder) 
      #  self.btn1.mouseCrusorOn.connect(self.change_loc) 

          # Folder Icon Part
        self.label1 = QLabel(self, text="직빠구리")
        self.label1.setGeometry(QRect(50, 5, 100, 50))
        self.label1.move(x1,y1) #위치
        pixmap=QPixmap("images/Folder.JPEG")
        self.label1.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.label1.setFixedSize(30,30)
        self.label1.setScaledContents(True)

        self.show()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self,e):
        x=e.x()
        y=e.y()
        text2="x:{0}, y:{1}".format(x,y)
        self.label_mouseTest.setText(text2)
        X=int(x/50)
        Y=int(y/50)
      #  if self.btn1.clicked():
        #    self.btn1.move(LocationX[X]-20,LocationY[Y]+30)
          #  self.label1.move(LocationX[X],LocationY[Y])
```

Comment: On each mouse-moved event, remember the previous location of the cursor. If the old location was outside the button and the new location is inside the button (or vice versa), restyle the button appropriately. The status of the *mouse* button is irrelevant.

Comment: I really Appreciate you for your help. I got the hint, so, you mean is, to apply mouse location with a "range of the button"...? Add if( "whether the cursor is inside X-range of Button" && "whether the cursor is inside Y-range of Button")